# why is this n(square) complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity

why is this code n^2 complexity when there are three for loops? and how do u tell the different complexity of the code? here is the code:

```
    int size1= sc.nextInt();
    int size2 = sc.nextInt();

    int value=0;
    for(int k=0;k<size1;k++)
    {
        value++;
        //5 times
        for(int x=0;x<size2;x++)
        {
            value++;
            //15 times
            for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                value++;
                //15 times
            }
        }
    }


    System.out.println(value);

}
```

Comment: nt sure wht u mean... size1 and size2?

Comment: who told you the complexity was O(n^2)?

Comment: the complete link is here, i amended a bit: https://nickboy.gitbooks.io/technical-interview-tutorial/content/dynamic_programming/post_office_problem.html

Comment: if your link size1=k. Therefore the complexity of the code is O(kn^2), ie O(n^2) with respect to n (for example if k is constant and small). You always compute complexities with respect to some variables.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of your code is `O(n^3)` if we assume that n=size1=size2.
[image: \sum_{k=0}^{size_1-1} \sum_{x=0}^{size_2-1} \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} 1=\sum_{k=0}^{size_1-1} \sum_{x=0}^{size_2-1}x=\sum_{k=0}^{size_1-1}\frac{(size_2-1)(size_2)}{2}=\frac{(size_1)(size_2)(size_2-1)}{2}=O(n^3)]

If only size2=n and size1=k (small constant), the complexity is O(kn^2), which is O(n^2) if we only consider the variable n to be large.

Comment: so this imply that there is no definite answer for the complexity? when size1=size2 and size1!=size2?

Comment: You always have to compute the complexity with respect to some variables. Here the complexity is **always** size1*size2*(size2-1)/2, ie k*n*(n-1)/2. But we generally write a complexity with a big O notation (like O(n^2)) and here this gives O(kn^2). Now you have to be aware of which variable is important and can be large. In your example k=2 and n is the variable that can take large values. Therefore the complexity is O(n^2). However, if k was of the order of n (which seems not to be the case here), the complexity would be O(n^3).

Comment: lets say if the size1 is only from 1-300 and size2 is only from 1-30, den could I just say that it is O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean complexity not efficiency.  The reason this is O(nˆ2) is that it has quadratic complexity because the third loop uses the second variable.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688720/what-is-order-of-complexity-in-big-o-notation).

Comment: if `n=size1=size2` the code runs in O(n^3). Even if the third loop uses the second variable it is still cubic. If we only consider the last two loops the instruction `value++;` will be executed n(n-1)/2 times

Comment: My answer was not link only. I clarified the question and answered in a simple way. without the link it is still a valid answer.