# Best practice on reading x-y binary data in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles

In a subroutine of my code I am reading 10M lines of binary integers, and subsequently process these. In the entire package this routine is called several thousands of times.
The code I'm using is:

```
for(l=0 ; l < nr_lines; l++) { 
// I use two temporary integers to store the numbers            
  fread(&ah, sizeof(int),1,file);
  fread(&bh, sizeof(int),1,file);
// and place them in the the corresponding array
  a[l] = ah;
  b[l] = bh;
}
```

I'm wondering whether the approach is inefficient as I call the fread function millions of time. Is it a better idea to first read the entire file into the memory, and subsequently parse it into the two arrays?

Update:

Based on suggestions below, I used the following code:

```
// read the entire file in one array
fread(c, sizeof(int),2*nr_lines, file); 
// and parse the code
for(l=0 ; l < nr_lines; l++) { 
    a[l] = c[2*l];
    b[l] = c[2*l+1];
}
```

The second approach is 5 times faster on my system for an binary file containing 2*30M entries (2.5 seconds vs. 0.5 seconds).

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what you mean by "far from optimal"?

Comment: Read a whole bunch of integers into an array of a size you can afford.

Comment: With far from optimal I mean I'm calling the fread function 10 million times, and from what I understand that may bad practice, slowing down the overal performance

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: The entire code takes about a day to run, I'm trying to improve performance where I can.

Comment: Ah, well that is slow, isn't it?  Read the entire file into memory first.  You're only talking about 40 megabytes.

Comment: A day? Not because of 10M `fread`s for sure.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It wouldn't surprise me in the least.  Each one of those freads is an OS call and probably a context switch.

Comment: The actual subsequent calculations are what really takes the time, but I cannot optimize there.
Especially as I run this chunk of code parallel I'm doubting whether calling fread millions of times is smart. I guess I'm answering my own question here.

Comment: Better to put `a[], b[]` into a `int` struct like `div_t pair[nr_lines]` and read once with `fread(pair, sizeof *pair,nr_lines,file);`

Comment: For true optimization, more of the code needs to be posted.  What you have here is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The entire code is a few hundreds on lines long, and this is the most obvious thing to optimize first, hence this post.
I'm working on solution now, and I'll get timings on either approach. @chux from what I read the div_t divides two numbers, correct?

Comment: The correct thing to do is remove all of the code, except the code that reads the file. Then time how long that takes. I'd be surprised if it takes more than a minute, which means that it's not even worth thinking about, given that the whole program takes a day.

Comment: @Comos `div_t div(a,b)` forms for the quotient and remainder and returns that as a `struct div_t`, a pair of `int` members.  But the larger point is that you are looking for _linear_ improvements  and that is **not** effective use of a programmers time near so much as seeking a reduction in [order of complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688720/what-is-order-of-complexity-in-big-o-notation), not just making something 2x or 4x faster.  IOWs, this code is **not** the problem and not the thing to optimize first.

Comment: I very much doubt this is the bottleneck. FILE* does some basic buffering, but anyway you could very quickly rewrite your code to use sscanf and %n from a block of memory to prove it. Learn to use a profiler such as `gprof`

Comment: @RobertHarvey `fread()` calls are buffered, so usually only one in several hundred calls to fread with size of an integer really causes a context switch, the rest is performed in userspace

Comment: @ctx: I get that, but how do you propose to improve the remainder of the code?  AFAICT the rest of the code *must* execute, and bringing it all into memory at once is a small price to pay to find out for sure if it's an I/O problem.  Give or take some Endian voodoo, you might even be able to address each `int` *directly* once it's in memory.

Comment: Right, so instead of it taking a day, now it takes, what, 4 hours?  This whole thing shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long did the actual read take?  With a bit of creative math, couldn't you just address your data directly from the `c` array?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The most efficient way is probably to `mmap()` the file and possibly `madvise()` for sequential reading then. But I doubt it will perform significantly better

Comment: @RobertHarvey, correct this is a small part of the code, and given that reading the binary files is done several thousand times this is a significant improvement. I'm new to stackoverflow, so I cannot upvote yet, but reading the entire file in memory in one fread did the trick.

Comment: @Cosmos 2.5 seconds vs. 0.5 seconds looks plausible, but where has the rest of the day gone? ;)

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(double)` in your second example?

Comment: *"I am reading 10M lines of binary integers"* -- `fread` has no concept of lines. It simply reads bytes. More good reading [When do function call costs still matter in modern compilers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357084/when-do-function-call-costs-still-matter-in-modern-compilers) see also [Tips for Optimizing C/C++ Code](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/papers/optimize.pdf)

Comment: @Ctx Thanks for your feedback, I wasn't aware the fread buffers 'under the hood'. The rest of the day was spend doing elaborate calculations on the information in the binary file ;) 
Many times for many different conditions...

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Thanks for that. There's actually more than one binary file involved, to keep it simple I was using the example of one file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm reading your suggestions now. Very helpful!

Comment: If your compiler have a parallel execution library and your hardware/OS supports it, maybe spawn multiple threads each reading/calculating a portion of the data. Then combine results from all threads at the end when all threads are done.